# Creating dynamic arrays in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, angular2-template

I am building a chart.js function in my angular2 web application. I want the bars in a bar chart to be red or green depending if their value is above or below a certain threshold. At the moment, I have a static solution which looks like this:

```
  public barChartLabels: string[] = ['06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00'];
  public barChartType: string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend: boolean = false;

  public barChartData: any[] = [
    {
      data: [85, 81, 80, 81, 56, 73, 70, 5, 0, 0, 65, 70, 83, 90, 85, 86, 84, 80, 87, 88, 82, 74, 71, 80],
      label: 'Values'
    }
  ];
private colors = [
    {
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(45, 227, 81, 0.2)',
        'rgba(45, 227, 81, 0.2)',
        'rgba(45, 227, 81, 0.2)',
        'rgba(45, 227, 81, 0.2)',
        'rgba(45, 227, 81, 0.2)',
        'rgba(45, 227, 81, 0.2)'
        // Potentially loads more colors
      ]
    }
  ];
```

However, this is messy and feels like overkill. I need a solution which will support the dynamic update of my data and simply compare the value to a threshold and return one or the other color. This has to be done in a way that I can bind to in an Angular2 Template. How should I do this?

## Update:

Here is the html:

```
<canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [colors]="colors" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend"
    [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Could you add the html?

Comment: @FabioAntunes Sure, please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html:

`...[colors]="getColors()"`

In your .ts file:

```
getColors() {
  return [{
     backgroundColor: this.barChartData.map(d => d > threshold ? red : green)
   }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really neat solution, but this only returns the background colour for the first bar...

Comment: I had to use `backgroundColor: this.barChartData[0].data.map(d => d > this.target ? red : green)`

Comment: Oh, and the `>` should be a `<`, but aside from that - a really nice solution!